# how to Check values present in javascript array or not

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

here is my javascript array  `alert(Parameter);` it alerts:

> Eqt_Param0=4.00,Eqt_Param1=0,Eqt_Param2=0

Now what I am trying to do is if any of the array elements values are equal to '0` i need to alert 'array does not contain all values,', so how to check whether array is empty or not.

Comment: This is almost unintelligible; what you say is a "JavaScript array" is an `alert()` function call.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you after whether the array has missing elements (e.g. `[0,1,,,,,6]`) or whether an element has a value of `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your array is a set of values of the form "key=number", and you want to know if any of the numbers are equal to zero.

The "proper" way to do it is:

```
var l = Parameter.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( Parameter[i].split("=")[0] == "0") {
        alert("Array does not contain all values");
        break;
    }
}
```

But you could just hax it:

```
if( (Parameter.join(",")+",").indexOf("=0,") > -1) {
    alert("Array does not contain all values");
}
```

Comment: @user1659450 you really should consider accepting the Answer, if it answers your question